# A small Help needed in a _Sql Converstion of Decimal_ using **CASE**

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am need to convert a value in to decimal.Before that I am checking a condition.I want to eliminate the decimal values if @tbt=1.

Eg if @tbt=1 then 15
   if @tbt=0 then 15.233

```
  declare @tbt int =1

   1) select 
    CASE WHEN @tbt=1 THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(24,0),15.23335)
    ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(24,3),15.23335) END

   2) select 
    CASE WHEN @tbt=1 THEN '1'
    ELSE '2' END
```

The first Query will returns 15.000.

1. Is it possible to get 15?

2. If  `CONVERT(DECIMAL(24,0),15.23335)` returns 15.then why it is coming 15.000 in the query.

For checking I used another query and it will prints 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use your current solution and add additional cast to Varchar(30) on both.

Answer (score 2):

You can't force it to return 2 separate datatypes like this depending on the CASE.

If you insert that result into a table using SELECT INTO syntax, you'll actually see the datatype is not DECIMAL(24,0) but DECIMAL(27,3)

i.e.

```
 declare @tbt int =1

 select 
 CASE WHEN @tbt=1 THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(24,0),15.23335)
 ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(24,3),15.23335) END AS Col
 INTO SomeTestTable

 --Now check the SomeTestTable schema
```

So what SQL Server has done, is rationalised it down to a single datatype definition that can fulfil BOTH cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH T(tbt, val) AS
(
select 1,15.23335 UNION ALL
select 0,15.23335
)

Select 
    CASE WHEN tbt=1 THEN cast( CONVERT(DECIMAL(24,0),val) as sql_variant)
    ELSE CONVERT(DECIMAL(24,3),val) END
FROM T
```

returns

```
15
15.233
```

Comment: @Harie - Lol! - Use your brain. If it works for 2 results it will work for just one!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to bw_üezi
 I got the answer after considering his advice. thanks for all others .

Here my answer..

```
declare @tbt int =0
  select 
  CASE WHEN @tbt=1 THEN CAST(CONVERT(DECIMAL(24,0),15.23335)AS NVARCHAR)
  ELSE CAST(CONVERT(DECIMAL(24,3),15.23335)AS NVARCHAR) END
```